# How to replace or get VCAP_SERVICES in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, migration, cloud-foundry, azure-aks, pcf

I am working on migrating a spring boot app to kubernetes which is currently placed on PCF and it is using a configuration class where it is getting values from VCAP_SERVICES that is picked up using the environment.getProperty().

I need to know how to manage this on AKS as I think VCAP_Service is PCF specific.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, you would use ConfigMap + Secret as a replacement for VCAP_Service. Example of ConfigMap file called **max_allowed_packet.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

Example of a secret file called mysql-secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mariadb-root-password
type: Opaque
data:
  password: S3ViZXJuZXRlc1JvY2tzIQ=
```

**kubectl apply -f mysql-secret.yaml**

References:
[https://opensource.com/article/19/6/introduction-kubernetes-secrets-and-configmaps#:~:text=Kubernetes%20has%20two%20types%20of,or%20volumes%20or%20environment%20variables](https://opensource.com/article/19/6/introduction-kubernetes-secrets-and-configmaps#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20has%20two%20types%20of,or%20volumes%20or%20environment%20variables).

https://cloudnative101.dev/electives/cf-to-k8s/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow the [Kubernetes Service Binding Spec](https://github.com/servicebinding/spec).

It builds on top of Kubernetes Secrets and defines a standard layout for how those secrets are mounted into a container. Instead of using an environment variable like `VCAP_SERVICES` it defines a folder/file structure on disk. You mount the secrets into the container following the specification.

The advantage is that applications, libraries, and services can all work together by following the specification.

A couple of examples that work with the K8s service binding spec:

1. If you're using Java & Spring Boot, the [Spring Cloud Bindings](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/) library will automatically read bindings and map them to Spring Boot configuration properties. This is very similar to how libraries will read properties out of `VCAP_SERVICES` and configure your application.
2. [Cloud-Native buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/), in particular [the Paketo Buildpacks implementations](https://paketo.io), will look for the presence of service bindings at build or run time to conditionally activate additional behaviors that require secret information such as credentials or license keys.